# Open a CSV in LibreOffice Calc without converting values to scientific notation

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

If I have a CSV file like this:

```
Id,Name,Reference
1,Alice,123EFG
2,Bob,456E89
3,Charles,7E9K2M
4,Donald,12345678E28496023749
```

and I open it in LibreOffice, some of the values are converted to scientific notation, like this:

[image: screenshot from LibreOffice]

Note that this is not just how the value is formatted for display. You can see from the formula box that actual value has been changed to scientific notation, so there is no way within LibreOffice at this point to recover the data that has been lost in this conversion.

**How can I open the file in LibreOffice without these values being converted to scientific notation?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try these options in the Text Import dialog:

1. Deselect the 'Detect Special Numbers' checkbox
2. In the preview area, click the column header where it is labeled 'Standard' and change it to 'Text'. According to the [documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Text_Import#Column_type):

   - Standard: LibreOffice determines the type.
   - Text: Imported data are treated as text.

[image]

Comment: If your answer has solved your problem then please accept your answer as the solution! Thanks.

Comment: I wonder how is it possible that both the question and the answer is posted at the same date and time!

Comment: @AmirRezazadeh Answering your own question is encouraged! https://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Liam of course, this helped me too. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!